# event not firing in backbone.js view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

This is my view for a single row as "tr".  I want want to click on the name cell and pop up a view for that cell. I could not get the event firing..

am I missing something? Thanks!

So this issue is solved by gumballhead, the issue I was having is that there needs to be a tagName associated with the ItemRowView. and then in the render function, I need to do self.$el.html(this.template(model));

Thought it might be helpful to share with..

```
    ItemRowView = Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize : function() {
    },
    template : _.template($('#item-row-template').html()),
    render : function() {       
        var self=this;        
        var model = this.model.toJSON();
        self.$el = this.template(model);
        return self.$el;
    },

    events : {
        "click td .item-name" : "viewOneItem"
             //Even if I change it to "click td":"viewOneItem", still not firing
    },
    viewOneItem : function() {
        console.log("click");
    }
});
```

collection View:

```
ItemsView = Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize : function() {
    },
    tagName : "tbody",

    render : function() {
        var self = this;
        this.collection.each(function(i) {
            var itemRowView = new ItemRowView({
                model : i
            });
            self.$el.append(itemRowView.render()); 
        });
        return self.$el;
    }

});
```

app view:
    AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
      this.items = new Items();

```
  this.items.fetch();
  this.itemsView = new ItemsView({collection:this.items});    

  $('#items-tbody').html(itemsView.render());

});
```

for template:

```
<script type="text/template" id="item-row-template">
<tr>
    <td class="item-name">{{name}}</td>
    <td>{{description}}</td>
</tr>
</script>

 <table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="items-tbody">

    </tbody>
 </table>
```

Comment: try `"click 'td .item-name'"` Backbone binds events by splitting by spaces i believe... it might have an issue with your selector. ah the delegated events (which these are) use a different splitter. ` var delegateEventSplitter = /^(\S+)\s*(.*)$/;`

Comment: @Cory: That won't work, the `events` parser won't know what the single quotes mean.

Comment: had a feeling it wouldn't like it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `"click td.item-name"` for your selector. You are currently listening for clicks on a descendant of td with the class "item-name".

FYI, you've also got a closing tag for an anchor element without an opening tag in your template.

Edit: I think you want  `self.$el.html(this.template(model));` rather than `self.$el = this.template(model);`

But there's no need to alias `this` to `self` with the code you posted.

Edit 2: Glad you got it sorted out. Let me give you an explanation.

All Backbone Views need a root element. That's the element that the events in the events hash are delegated to on instantiation. When a Backbone View is instantiated without an existing element, it will create one based on configuration settings like `tagName`, whose default is `"div"`. The element won't appear in the DOM until you explicitly inject it.

So when you set self.$el in your render method, you were overwriting the root element (along with the events, though they would have never fired because it would have listened for a click on a td that was a descendant of a div that didn't exist in the DOM).

As a side note, and it would not be the right way to do it in your case, you could have done `this.setElement($(this.template(model));` to redelegate the events from the div created on instantation to the tr created by your original template.

Comment: Thanks, I have fixed the anchor. I have specified "<td class="item-name">{{name}}</td>" in the template that the class be "item-name".... even if I remove the class name and do "click td", it still won't work..

Comment: Thanks, I'm getting "Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'createDocumentFragment' " when I use self.$el.html() here...

Comment: Are you initializing your view with an element?

Comment: In the collections, while looping the models, I did:   var itemRowView = new ItemsRowView({model : i});  Then i appended itemRowView to collection view's render... You mean do something in the initialize function for the ItemsRowView? Thanks!

Comment: But are your ItemsRowViews managing elements that exist on the page already or is the intention to dynamically add them? Are your models part of a collection? You may want to post the code for your table view too.

Comment: OK...how about this.  Change your template to remove the <tr> tags.  Add a property to ItemView for `tagName: "tr"`.  In ItemView's render, `return this` (it's convention). In your CollectionView's render, make sure to do `itemRowView.render().$el.appendTo(this.el);`

Comment: THanks, so I have removed the tr from template and added tagName. When I log itemRowView.render(), it's not generating the <tr> tag.  I only get <td></td><td></td>.... I have posted my full code... I really really appreciate your help!

Comment: I have it solved, you are right, the issue is that I'm missing a tagName...then I did self.$el .html(this.template(model)) and it worked, may be is it forced to generate a tagName inorder to make this event firing work.... Thanks:)

Comment: It's a little confusing, especially if you're new to Backbone. See my update for an explanation.